# gdb vs lldb which is better for a new in object-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb, lldb

i am new in Objective-C, and no experience in gdb or lldb, with Xcode4.2 , which is better for me 
to learn ?

Comment: lldb - it is the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest GDB. We have tested LLDB which is supposed to be much better but as far as our usage gets it makes lots of errors -> errors like you are debugging your code and you have seen it work, with the GDB it is as expected, with LLDB you see some really strange values and it may lead to dramatic refactors which are not needed and even mistaken

Answer (score 1):

I am from the future.
LLDB is now(2016) not the future of Xcode but just present with LLVM.

Here is the quotation from Apple official link about this topic :

> About LLDB and Xcode
>
> With the release of Xcode 5, the LLDB debugger becomes the foundation for the > debugging experience on OS X.
>
> LLDB is Apple’s “from the ground up” replacement for GDB, developed in close coordination with the LLVM compilers to bring you state-of-the-art debugging with extensive capabilities in flow control and data inspection. Starting with Xcode 5, all new and preexisting development projects are automatically reconfigured to use LLDB.
>
> The standard LLDB installation provides you with an extensive set of commands designed to be compatible with familiar GDB commands. In addition to using the standard configuration, you can easily customize LLDB to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

LLDB as the last XCode version 4.3.2 uses it

Comment: Normally, I would approve what Apple recommends by default, but in this case they screwed up big time. Read the answer by Dani_TT.